# How do we achieve and pushAndRemoveUntil using GetX in flutter?

Tags: flutter, navigation, flutter-getx

How can I implement

```
 Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (BuildContext context) => SignInScreen()),
              ModalRoute.withName(GetRoutes.home),
            );
```

in flutter using GetX navigation?

Comment: Get.offAll(Home());    and with named      
Get.offNamedUntil('home', (route) => false);

Comment: But this will not take the user to SignInScreen right ? @Aks

Comment: remove the "home()" from Get.offAll with your SignInScreen() and remove 'home' from Get.offNamedUntil with your 'named route'

Answer (score -1):

To implement this code in Flutter using GetX navigation, you can use the following code:

```
Get.offAllNamed(GetRoutes.signIn);
```

This will push the `SignInScreen` widget to the stack and remove all previous routes, including the route to the `GetRoutes.home` screen.

Below code is an example of how to use the `Get.offAllNamed()` method in a GetX widget:

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('My Widget'),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Get.offAllNamed(GetRoutes.signIn);
            },
            child: Text('Sign In'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When the user clicks on the `Sign In` button, they will be taken to the `SignInScreen` widget and all previous routes will be removed.

Comment: My requirement is the Home Screen should not be removed. All others should be.